# How to configure Inventory detail in Item fulfillment by restlet in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am new to NetSuite domain. I want to create item Fulfillment from salces Order through RestLet post method. But when I send the data from postman show   error that Please configure the inventory detail in line 2 of the item list.

/**

*@NApiVersion 2.x

*@NScriptType Restlet

*/

define(["N/search", "N/record", "N/cache", "N/log", "N/error",],

```
function (search, record, cache, log, error) {

    function _post(context) {

        try {

            if (context != null && context != "") {

                var recidArr = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < context.length; i++) {

                    var contextObj = context[i];

                    log.debug("contextObj", contextObj);

                    var salesOrderId = contextObj.salesOrderId;

                    var trandate = contextObj.trandate;

                    var ifStage = contextObj.ifStage;

                    var memo = contextObj.memo;

                    var itemList = contextObj.itemList;

                    var tranDetail = search.lookupFields({

                        type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,

                        id: salesOrderId,

                        columns: 'status'

                    });

                    var soStatusDetail = tranDetail.status

                    var soStatus = soStatusDetail[0].text

                    if (soStatus == "Partially Fulfilled" || soStatus == "Pending Fulfillment") {

                        var itemFulfillmentObj = record.transform({

                            fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,

                            fromId: salesOrderId,

                            toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,

                            isDynamic: true,

                        });

                        if (trandate) {

                            itemFulfillmentObj.setText("trandate", trandate);

                        }

                        if (memo) {

                            itemFulfillmentObj.setValue("memo", memo);

                        }

                        itemFulfillmentObj.setValue("shipstatus", "B");

                        if (ifStage) {

                            itemFulfillmentObj.setValue("custbody_xxflx_fulfillmentstage", ifStage);

                        }

                        /// configure item fulfillment line label value

                        if (itemList) {

                            for (var j = 0; j < itemList.length; j++) {

                                var itemlistObject = itemList[j];

                                var item = itemlistObject.item;

                                var location = itemlistObject.location;

                                var quantity = itemlistObject.quantity;

                                var inventoryDetail = itemlistObject.inventoryDetail;// this is inventory detail configuration

                                var checkLotSerial = fetchItemLotOrSerial(item);

                                log.debug('checkLotSerial for item:', JSON.stringify(checkLotSerial) + '(item:)' + item)

                                var itemLine = itemFulfillmentObj.findSublistLineWithValue({

                                    sublistId: 'item',

                                    fieldId: 'item',

                                    value: item

                                });

                                if (itemLine >= 0) {

                                    itemFulfillmentObj.selectLine({

                                        sublistId: 'item',

                                        line: itemLine

                                    });

                                    itemFulfillmentObj.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                        sublistId: "item",

                                        fieldId: "itemreceive",

                                        value: true,

                                    });

                                    if (quantity) {

                                        itemFulfillmentObj.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                            sublistId: "item",

                                            fieldId: "quantity",

                                            value: quantity,

                                        });

                                    }

                                    

                                    if (location) {

                                        itemFulfillmentObj.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                            sublistId: "item",

                                            fieldId: "location",

                                            value: location,

                                        });

                                    }

                                    /// configure inventory details configuration

                                    if (checkLotSerial.isSerialized == true || checkLotSerial.isLot == true) {

                                        if (inventoryDetail) {

                                            var inventoryDetails = itemFulfillmentObj.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({

                                                sublistId: 'item', // inventory or item

                                                fieldId: 'inventorydetail',

                                            });

                                            for (var k = 0; k < inventoryDetail.length; k++) {

                                                var lotSerialNo = inventoryDetail[k].lotSerialNo

                                                var qty = inventoryDetail[k].qty

                                                var status = inventoryDetail[k].status

                                                inventoryDetails.selectNewLine({

                                                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'

                                                });

                                                if (lotSerialNo) {

                                                    inventoryDetails.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                                        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',

                                                        fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',

                                                        value: lotSerialNo

                                                    });

                                                }

                                                if (qty) {

                                                    inventoryDetails.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                                        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',

                                                        fieldId: 'quantity',

                                                        value: qty

                                                    });

                                                }

                                                if (status) {

                                                    inventoryDetails.setCurrentSublistValue({

                                                        sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',

                                                        fieldId: 'inventorystatus',

                                                        value: status

                                                    });

                                                }

                                                inventoryDetails.commitLine({

                                                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'

                                                });

                                            }

                                        }

                                        else {

                                            throw 'no inventory detail found for a lot/serial controlled item'

                                        }

                                    }

                                 

                                }

                                else {

                                    throw 'items not found for fulfilment'

                                }

                                itemFulfillmentObj.commitLine({

                                    sublistId: "item",

                                });

                            }

                        }

                        var itemFulfillmentId = itemFulfillmentObj.save({

                            enableSourcing: true,

                            ignoreMandatoryFields: true,

                        });

                        log.debug("itemFulfillmentId", itemFulfillmentId);

                        if (itemFulfillmentId) {

                            recidArr.push(itemFulfillmentId);

                        }

                    }

                }

                if (recidArr.length > 0) {

                    return {

                        success: true,

                        status: "200",

                        created: "Records Created Successfully : " + recidArr

                    };

                } else {

                    return {

                        success: false,

                        status: "500",

                        message: "No Records Created"

                    };

                }

            }

        } catch (err) {

            log.debug({

                title: "POST",

                details: JSON.stringify(err),

            });

            return err;

        }

    }

    ///// GET |||

    function get(datain) {

        try {

            if (!isEmpty(datain)) {

                //var recIdArr = []

                // for (var i = 0; i < datain.length; i++) {

                var contextObj = datain[i];

                log.debug('contextObj', contextObj)

                var ifId = datain.ifId;

                var ifStatus = datain.ifStatus;

                if (!isEmpty(ifId) && !isEmpty(ifStatus)) {

                    record.submitFields({

                        type: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,

                        id: ifId,

                        values: { 'custbody_xxflx_fulfillmentstage': ifStatus },

                    })

                    return "IF has been updated successfully, Id: " + ifId

                }

                // }

            }

        } catch (e) {

            log.debug(e.name, e.message);

            return {

                success: false,

                status: "500",

                message: e.message

            };

        }

    }

    function fetchItemLotOrSerial(item) {

        var isSerialized;

        var isLot;

        if (item != null && item != '') {

            var itemSearchObj = search.create({

                type: "item",

                filters: [

                    ["internalid", "is", item]

                ],

                columns: [

                    search.createColumn({

                        name: "isserialitem"

                    }),

                    search.createColumn({

                        name: "islotitem"

                    })

                ]

            });

            var cols = itemSearchObj.columns;

            var searchResultCount = itemSearchObj.runPaged().count;

            itemSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {

                isSerialized = result.getValue(cols[0]);

                isLot = result.getValue(cols[1]);

                log.debug('isSerialized', isSerialized);

                log.debug('isLot', isLot);

                return true;

            });

        }

        return {

            isSerialized: isSerialized,

            isLot: isLot

        };

    }

    function isEmpty(obj) {

        return obj == null || obj == '' || obj == undefined;

    }

    return {

        post: _post,

        get: get,

    };

});
```